# Upgrade magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4, upgrade, repositories

Hello after reading many threads i read that following are the steps in order to update magento with composer

1. composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.4 --no-update
2. composer update

As result i got following error: https://ibb.co/Mnw4p0H

In order to fix i tried

1. auth.json with repo username/password
2. composer.json with following: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4/composer.json
3. added into composer.json following

   "repositories": [
   {
   "type": "composer",
   "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
   }
   ],

but nothing to do..
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> **Run below Commands**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento s:d:c

php bin/magento in:rein

php bin/magento c:c
```

**Note: Remove your updated file composer.json and add your older composer.json file if you update composer.lock file then also remove it and add your older composer.lock file. You do not add or remove any file from the existing Magento. When you run the command it will automatically update files that are required.**

Answer (score 0):

backup the `composer.lock` file to the `composer.lock.bk` and remove the `composer.lock` file and try again with the below command

```
composer2 require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.4 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: failed. Here the issue i got.. https://ibb.co/7nYgRM1
https://ibb.co/C0k1cRq